# How to print words n words in shell ?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

This is what I have tried. It works but sometimes the words printed are not of $len size.

```
LINE=$($SHUF <"$fileName" | tr  ' \011' '\012' |  head -n "$len" | tr '\n' '   ')
echo "$LINE"
```

For my program, I need to print exactly ($len) amount of words. I am unable to achieve this. My shuffle function is working fine. The contents of the file are like this:

`getting and picking the
and picking the daisies
picking the daisies when
the daisies when suddenly
daisies when suddenly a`

Expected output after shuffling for $len = 4

`picking the daisies suddenly`

Note: The output can be any random words extracted from the file. Just needs to be of specified length $len.

Comment: what do you thing `tr '\011' '\012'` is doing? Don't you want to sub all spaces with `\n`? Good luck.

Comment: It is removing the spaces. No, I do not want to sub all the spaces with \n. I need to print a continuous string just with one space no new lines.  Thank you.

Comment: `man ascii` should show you that you're replacing tab chars with LineFeed chars (`\n`). Skip the assignment(`LINE=$(`), the `shuf` and just start with `head -10 "$filename"`, then keep adding each of your pipeline elements and confirm that each additional step is making the change you need. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I will look into doing it that way. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$ words=( $(<input.txt) )
$ fourwords() { local sp=""; local a=( "$@" ); for ((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do printf '%s%s' "$sp" "${a[@]:$((RANDOM%${#a[@]})):1}"; sp=" "; done; echo; }
$ fourwords "${words[@]}"
and and the the
$ fourwords one two three four five
two one two three
```

- This creates an array of all the words in your input file,
- creates a function which

  - runs a for-loop `$limit` times which
  - prints a random word from the array.

Result of that function is shown using the `$words[]` array as well as simple strings.

If you felt compelled, you could support custom word counts.

```
$ nwords() { local limit="$1"; shift; local sp=""; local a=( "$@" ); for ((i=1;i<=limit;i++)); do printf '%s%s' "$sp" "${a[@]:$((RANDOM%${#a[@]})):1}"; sp=" "; done; echo; }
$ nwords 3 "${words[@]}"
picking getting the
$ nwords 5 {1..1000}
428 915 636 228 22
```

Comment: Yes, something like this. I already have the words in the four-word format. All I need to do is print them one by one using my shuffle function for n times (specified by the user.) You gave me a good idea of implementing it using arrays, I will look into that for sure. Thank you! :)